# Visual Studio Code Jupyter Notebooks: Keyboard shortcuts not working

Tags: visual-studio-code, jupyter, keyboard-shortcuts

I am trying to get the integrated Jupyter environment up and running for my VSCode installation. I have the Jupyter extension enabled and can edit and run Python and Markdown cells without issue. However, none of the default keyboard shortcuts work when I am in edit mode. For example, in the below screenshot, I am trying to advance to the next cell using 'Ctrl+Alt+]' but nothing happens when I am in the editor. I believe the criteria for using the shortcut in the "when" column are met which is why I am confused. Am I not in the right context for the shortcut, or am I missing something?

https://i.stack.imgur.com/HX8za.jpg

I tried all the stated keyboard shortcuts, making my own keyboard shortcut, reinstalling the extension, looking for similar issues online. This issue does not appear to exist in the same form here.